# Unity Update() performance

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have two functionality that need to achieve:

1. movement
2. rotation

both must be in `Update()`, i can combine it but i prefer both of them in separate script in each `Movement.cs and Rotation.cs`.

So i have two method:

1. Combine both into one script in and using one `Update()`.
2. Separate into two script and each of them have `Update()`.

> My question : does it cost performance if separate them into each individual `Update()` instead of combine in one script with one `Update()`.

Both script will be attach on one object, so if i have hundreds of object.

`Method 1` - 100 objects and 100 script with `Update()`.
`Method 2` - 100 objects and 200 script with `Update()`.

> Another question : is it really bad to do `Method 2` ?.

Answer (score 4):

This is a case of micro-optimisation. You should use any of the methods that makes more sense in your particular case and after you're done you should to some profiling.

Based on the results of profiling you'll end up knowing where and what to optimise.

Getting back to the problem at hand having 2 Updates will cost you one more function call per frame and some time when your MonoBehaviour is first loaded, but that is negligible, you'll eat **a lot more** CPU cycles in other parts of your code.

Answer (score 3):

If you can combine, do it. The Unity MonoBehaviours are usefull but eat quickly your resources, especially if you have many scripts running at the same time.

Check this blog ticket : https://blogs.unity3d.com/2015/12/23/1k-update-calls/

> WHAT SHOULD YOU DO?
>
> Of course it all depends on your project, but in the field it’s not rare to see a game using a large number of GameObjects in the scene each executing some logic every frame. Usually it’s a little bit of code which doesn’t seem to affect anything, but when the number grows very large the overhead of calling thousands of Update methods starts to be noticeable.

Comment: thats a good link. anyway i think my object will be not more than 300. which is if i use method 2, i will have 600 Update(). and it is for mobile. do you think it is fine ?

Comment: Nothing is better than testing ! But especially on mobile, if you can save resources without much effort, do it. You don't really know the power of the mobile your players will have.

Comment: ya, i think i will try first second method first. and check for profiler. and try most highest possible to test the limit.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps a third option would be better for you, it elaborates on the first option but still splits your logic into two separate areas, thus achieving the loose coupling you were going for originally.

```
public static class Manipulators
{
    public static void Rotate(MonoBehaviour behaviour, float amount)
    {
        Transform t = behaviour.GetComponent<Transform>();
        // Do stuff with t
    }

    public static void Move(MonoBehaviour behaviour, float amount)
    {
        Transform t = behaviour.GetComponent<Transform>();
        // Do stuff with t
    }
}
```

Then in your monobehaviour...

```
public void Update()
{
    Manipulators.Rotate(this, 15f);
    Manipulators.Move(this, 15f);
}
```

Comment: this look nice, i will test this method too

Comment: Since `GetComponent` is a "heavy" method, I would suggest to give the Transform component directly as parameter an cache the transform component of the monoBehaviour in the Awake / Start function

Answer (score 0):

Here are some tests I did on how `Update()` compares to some common Unity3d functions.

In the scene there are **10000 empty GameObjects** with UpdateTest script on them.

The Average FPS value is smoothed heavily and I use the Mono backend.

So it seems the cost of `Update()` function is somewhat less than moving an empty `GameObject` with `transform.localposition`.

I've used Unity3d 2020.1.5

[image: Update() and manager function test images]